# Add start price and add on price

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with a starting price and a select drop down with different options.
I want that starting price to change based on the drop down selection.

```
<div id="price">$50.00</div>

<select>
    <option value="1">Option 1 (+$50.00)</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2 (+$100.00)</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3 (+$150.00)</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4 (+$200.00)</option>
</select>
```

I am using this code but it is not working

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var total = 0;

    $('select option:selected').each(function() {
        var m = /\(\+ \$(\d+\.\d+)\)/.exec(this.value);

        if(m !== null) {
            total += +m[1];
        }
    });

    var decimalPart = (total - Math.floor(total)) * 100;

    $('#finalPrice').text('$' + Math.floor(total) + '.' + (decimalPart < 10 ? '0' : '') + decimalPart);
});
```

Not exactly sure whats going on

Comment: Why not see the `value` attribute of the option to the be the monetary value? Save a TON of code.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @tymeJV yes, or even use an `data-money-value`, or whatever.  Crazy to regex the value out of a label.

Comment: Not sure what is going on? Use the javascript debugger! Set breakpoint inside your change method. Check the values of your vars. Then you know when something is happen that you do not expect. Then you can ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest reconfiguring your data to be outside of presentation and an attribute on your elements.

```
<div id="price" data-price="50.00">$50.00</div>

<select>
    <option value="1" data-price="50.00">Option 1 (+$50.00)</option>
    <option value="3" data-price="100.00">Option 2 (+$100.00)</option>
    <option value="4" data-price="150.00">Option  (+$150.00)</option>
    <option value="5" data-price="200.00">Option 4 (+$200.00)</option>
</select>


Total: <div id="finalPrice">$50.00</div>
```

And for your script:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var total = $("#price").data("price")*1;

    $('select option:selected').each(function() {
        total += $(this).data("price")*1;
    });

    $('#finalPrice').text('$' + total.toFixed(2));
});
```

[**Requisite Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GKXC7/)

Additionally, it sounded like you wanted a "final price" on top of the listed price, so I created an additional div to hold that value.  If you wanted to reuse the same "price," you could simply replace the `$('#finalPrice')` selection with `$('#price')` and it will operate as desired.

Answer (score 0):

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcpDESIGNS/76tPK/)**

Just save the value within the options `value` attribute. Much simpler!

```
<select>
    <option value="50.00">Option 1 (+$50.00)</option>
    <option value="100.00">Option 2 (+$100.00)</option>
    <option value="150.00">Option  (+$150.00)</option>
    <option value="200.00">Option 4 (+$200.00)</option>
</select>
```

And the Javascript. We simply get the original value, remove the $ sign. And add it to the `this.value` from the dropdown.

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var originalPrice = parseFloat( $('#price').text().replace('$', '') );
    var total = parseFloat(this.value) + originalPrice;

    $('#finalPrice').text('$' + total.toFixed(2));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="price" data-value='50.00'>$50.00</div>

<select>
    <option value="1" data-value='50.00'>Option 1 (+$50.00)</option>
    <option value="2" data-value='100.00'>Option 2 (+$100.00)</option>
    <option value="3" data-value='150.00'>Option 3 (+$150.00)</option>
    <option value="4" data-value='200.00'>Option 4 (+$200.00)</option>
</select>

<div id="finalPrice"></div>
```

.js:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var total = parseFloat($('#price').data('value'));

    $('select option:selected').each(function() {
        var m = parseFloat($(this).data('value'));

        if(m !== null) {
            total += m;
        }
    });
    $('#finalPrice').data('value', total.toFixed(2));
    $('#finalPrice').text('$' + total.toFixed(2));
});
```

Now, understandably this gets a little more complicated if you're using non-0 decimal places.

Edit: here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/remus/ACnsp/